# Подключение плагинов

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, appdomain

Хочу подключить плагин с папки, которая лежит в папке проекта, но не в папке с exeшником.
при подключении через `Assembly.Load` и передавая путь Dll вылетает:

> Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "D:\github\lab\oopLabs\PCRelated\PCRelated\dll\AES\AES\obj\Debug\MyAes.dll" либо одну из их зависимостей. Данное имя сборки или база кода недействительны. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131047)

Читал инфу про `AppDomain` , но везде намудренно всё, можете объяснить , пожалуйста, про `AppDomain` и как это решить?

Comment: А почему лежит не в папке с программой? Почитайте документацию, Fusion Log в исключении, и попробуйте `LoadFrom` вместо `Load`.